# What is this serif font with distinctive T?

Tags: font-identification

I'm attempting to find this font (note the distinctive shape of the T):

[image]

I tried automated identification (WhatTheFont, Identifont, and Serf-font identification guide), but didn't find it.

Sorry about the poor quality of the sample; it's the best I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Baker Signet](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/baker-signet/) looks very close:

[image]